# How to make a custom dialog screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I would like to make a rich custom dialog screen in a way that is similar to the one found in the TestFlight app, [as shown here](http://tokentoken.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/TestFlight-iPad-768x1024.png)

Can a `UIAlertController` be customised for this purpose? And if so how? Or should I be using a different component altogether?

Comment: FYI - that's a custom view controller presented with a "form sheet" modal presentation. Very standard stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UIAlertController cannot be used for that screen.

I would suggest creating your own view, with its own xib.

Write it so it works similar to UIAlertController, in that you can request the screen, supplying it with parameters or an object to fill in all relevant data, and the present it from the requesting ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a UIAlertController. As every view controller has a view, alert controller also has subviews. Create a custom view. Remove all default subviews from alert controller. Add your custom subview to alert controller's view.